# Is there a function/library that parses the DESCRIPTION file into a list object?

Tags: r, parsing, text-parsing, cran

### MOTIVATION

I am wanting to build a PACKAGE-RANKING algorithm based on various measures of optimality.

I was reading something today [tidyverse], that pointed to the following command:

#### ELEMENT

```
tools::package_dependencies(package="liteq", recursive=TRUE)[["liteq"]]
```

Which could easily be wrapped into a function (WORK IN PROGRESS):

```
help.packageInfo = function(package, key="dependencies", ...)
    {
    # number of authors
    # function to PARSE DESCRIPTION FILE
    
    tools::package_dependencies(package=package, recursive=TRUE)[[package]];
    }
```

#### EXAMPLE [GOOD]

```
help.packageInfo("digest");
```

#### EXAMPLE [BAD]

```
help.packageInfo("tidyverse");
```

### HOW to extract `DESCRIPTION` file data

```
Package: tools
Version: 4.2.1
Priority: base
Title: Tools for Package Development
Author: R Core Team
Maintainer: R Core Team <do-use-Contact-address@r-project.org>
Contact: R-help mailing list <r-help@r-project.org>
Description: Tools for package development, administration and documentation.
License: Part of R 4.2.1
Suggests: codetools, methods, xml2, curl, commonmark, knitr, xfun,
        mathjaxr
NeedsCompilation: yes
Built: R 4.2.1; x86_64-w64-mingw32; 2022-06-23 09:27:10 UTC; windows
ExperimentalWindowsRuntime: ucrt
```

The description file can tell me lots of things (number of authors, number of suggests, imports, requires) even for NON-CRAN repositories I have installed onto my system.  I am trying to ask, is their a library/function that you have seen that parses the `DESCRIPTION` file into a list object?

Answer (score 7):

In the comments it is pointed out that

```
pkg <- "stats"
packageDescription(pkg)
```

is even shorter.

If what you have is not an installed package but rather just a DESCRIPTION file then use the read.dcf shown below.

---

Assuming that the package is installed get the path to the DESCRIPTION file and then use read.dcf giving a one row matrix whose columns hold the data.

```
pkg <- "stats"
desc_path <- system.file("DESCRIPTION", package = pkg)
m <- read.dcf(desc_path)
```

That could be used as is or converted into various forms depending on what you want.

```
DF <- as.data.frame(m) # one row data.frame

stack(DF) # 2 column data.frame

as.list(DF) # named list

unlist(DF) # named character vector
```

Comment: If the package is installed, `utils::packageDescription()` is even simpler.

Comment: @user2554330 That would require a "CRAN" package, no?

Comment: Found this *RTM* [`inst <- packageStatus()$inst; inst[inst$Status != "ok", c("Package", "Version", "Status")]`

Comment: The issue is *NOT* to show the generic info.  It is to `extract` the info.  The `readdcf` is written in `C` and merges the actions `readfile` with `parse.dcf`.  And it doesn't parse the content beyond HI-LEVEL keys and values.  I want to know how many authors, roles, etc.  That is what I mean by `extract` the info.